# Check if values in cell A1 A2 and A3 are unique

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'd like to use a formula to check that values in "n" cells (let's say 3) are unique.

I found ways to highlight duplicates, but i'd like a formula that returns 1 if there is a duplicate or 0 if 3 cells are unique.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=(COUNTUNIQUE(A1:A3)<>COUNTA(A1:A3))*1
```